# Get HTML from Yahoo page using Python

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to get the HTML code from a Yahoo page (not API) using Python and its requests module but can't seem to get past the login/auth page. Do I need to use a more complex authentication for Yahoo?

```
import requests
user = 'user'
password = 'password'
myURL = 'https://football.fantasysports.yahoo.com/'
response = requests.get(url=myURL, auth(user,password))
r = response.text
print r
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `auth=(user, password)`?

Comment: Yahoo likely does not support login by authorization header in this manner.